# android design pattern - list with only one item -> show item instead of list

Tags: android, design-patterns, listactivity

I have a question around ListActivities, put into an example for hopefully more clarity. ;)

My application has a TitleListActivity which shows the published titles  of a particular author. This list might contain one or more titles depending on the author. When there is only one title in the list i want to immediately start the TitleViewActivity for the particular title rather than showing the boring list with one title. I assume pretty common thing, just havent found any explanation on it so far.

Easy approach would be to check before calling the TitleListActivity how many titles there are for this author and start the respective activity. As the TitleListActivity call can happen from different parts of the application I would like to centralize the logic which decides what Activity to call.

My question is what is the best practice to achieve this. Can this logic be added to the TitleListActivity in my example efficiently.  All the history back button logic etc should work of course.

Any suggestion highly appreciated

Thanks

martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably make a Activity launcher class/controller with a static method for launching the TitleList or Title. Would be something like ActivityLauncher.lauchAuthorActivity(context, auther) and that function would decide on what activity to launch.

Comment: Thanks a lot Heinrisch, that is what i came up with until now also (I put it the ApplicationClass as static method. I am okay with it but still wondering is there a way at "very early" start of an Activity to decide if another Activity should be started instead...

Comment: Well the best thing is not to launch the wrong activity at all. You could probably launch a new activity oncreate and finish the one you started that was wrong. But that is not very nice. The life cycle of a activity can be viewed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: I agree with you Heinrisch. My hesitation comes from the idea that the decision if a list is displayed or in the case of only one title the title view itself should lie within the ListActivity authority. That is why I was wondering what is a good design pattern for this situation but most likely i am just thinking nonsense here. Maybe I could move the launcher logic to the TitleListActivity class to have it with its domain. With this I should be satisfied I guess :) Thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `Intent.putExtra()` instead of static method or class.

You must have already been using something like a AuthorId to get respective author's Titles.

Just use 1 more attribute TitleCount

```
intent.putExtra("TitleCount", n);
```

check it in TitleListActivity, and if its 1 finish() TitleListActivity in the 1st line of onCreate and open the Title Page.

If you are getting all the data of Titles(including the Title count) in the TitleListActivity check the `Array/ArrayList size` which has these titles.

Comment: Thanks a lot Archie for the feedback. From my vage feeling it seems right to call ListActivity in any case and it should be its authority to decide if it shows a list or forwards to start another Activity in the case only one item could be shown. But what I am wondering is how expensive this additional startActivity is which I have in this case when there is only one item and I could call the TitleViewActivity also directly. I expect there is quite something going on under the android hood when you call startActivity ...

Comment: In that case try to make the check in the previous activity itself. Before going to TitleListActivity check if count is 1. and if yes then go directly to the TitleViewActivity instead of going to TitleListActivity and getting redirected(extra startActivity). But i dont think this extra startActivity will a problem.

Comment: Thx. That is my approach right now and also what was recommended by Heinrisch. It works fine, my whole post was just about what is the recommended way to go in order to learn about android design pattern. As most of us I highly appreciate design pattern so as I am new to Android I try to find out ...